# GZIP a String in Android

Tags: java, android, compression

I'm experiencing a weird issue when compressing a String using GZIPOutputStream.
This is my method:

```
private byte[] gzippedDataFromString(String string)
{       

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;

    try 
    {   
        gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        gzos.write(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        gzos.flush();

        return baos.toByteArray();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new BopplRESTfulClientException(ex);
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (gzos != null) try { gzos.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {};
    }

}
```

I've tried to compress this JSON string:

```
{
  "facebook_ids": [
"8586904507",
"1000047662932846"
  ],
  "google_ids": [
"1082138329001828286757"
  ]
}
```

I get the right bytes using `getBytes("UTF-8")`, so I think the issue is in:

```
gzos.write(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
gzos.flush();
```

When I print gzipped data (in hex), I get:

```
1F 8B 08 00 etc (only zeroes after this point)
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: What do you get instead of the correct string?

Comment: `1F 8B 08 00 etc (only zeroes after this point)`. It looks like a failed compression.

Comment: It's Android, and I'm using Java6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close the `GZIPOutputStream` before trying to fetch the `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
    gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
    gzos.write(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzos.flush();
    gzos.close();

    return baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos, true);
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html#GZIPOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29) for more details. Also, you should `.close()` your `GZIPOutputStream`.

---

If you can afford using Guava 14+, use a `Closer`:

```
final Closer closer = Closer.create();

ByteArrayOutputStream out;
GZIPOutputStream gz;

try {
    out = closer.register(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    gz = closer.register(new GZIPOutputStream(out, true));
    gz.write(string.getBytes("UTF-8");
    gz.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw closer.rethrow(e);
} finally {
    closer.close();
}

return out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can send data from Android side (API level 10+) in GZIP compressed format

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-encoding", "gzip");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
GZIPOutputStream dos1 = new GZIPOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
dos1.write(content.getBytes());
dos1.flush();
dos1.close();

BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String decodedString1 = "";
while ((decodedString1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
  Log.e("!!!",decodedString1);
}
in1.close();
```